# What is the Client/Server Equivalent for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#

I used to build a website on ASP.NET MVC. Now I want to build another web service. This time, I want to use a client application (running on Windows) and no web pages are needed. What technology should I choose? I am still using C# on both server- and client-side, and I might use mySQL. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), which is new in [ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) <sup><1></sup>.

<sub>ASP.NET MVC 4 is under RC by the time of writing.</sub>

Comment: No it is not. Web API is intended for sites that want to expose they own API in addition to just being websites. If you want to build web-services, you should stick to WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest WPF for client side. It has a similar MVC architecture and uses XAML for UI which is simple to learn but very powerful. Server can be a service if no gui is needed.

Comment: What technology should I use on server-side?

Comment: Well it depends on a type of application. If it is some kind of CRUD application i would suggest WCF (Windows Communication Foundation). With it you get the benefit of RMI system that you can easily connect to and call methods like your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a classic 3-tiers architecture:

- UI client application in WPF (which provides the nice MVVM pattern for UI/Logic separation)
- WCF webservices for the backoffice, IIS hosting (C# assemblies)
- Entity Framework as an ORM